# How much Ram do I need for ElasticSearch for my site?

Tags: elasticsearch, memory, digital-ocean, ram

I am going to need a full text search with ElasticSearch on a 2 Gb database for my site, with 500k visitors per month (max 250 users at the same time). So, I need to figure out what is the best server in digitalocean for me, with the minimum cost...

How much ram do i need?

Comment: Your question is way too broad to answer and runs the risk of being closed for that reason. 2GB DB doesn't mean much if we don't know 1) how the data looks like (i.e. schema); 2) how you want to analyze it; 3) how the users will need to search it... and a host of other corollary questions...

Comment: Thanx. My Site is an Ecommerce, so I need to provide search by a number of text fields. Db mainly have two tables: 'bussiness' and 'products' and the user is going to search by tags, keywords, categories, and 10 other fields. I need just an estimation, to know what kind of hosting do I need. Thank u very much.